# Determine Number of Coins

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, programming

A jar holding 1 cent, 5 cent and 10 cent coins contains twelve coins with a total value of 86 cent. How many coins of each type are in the box? (Preferably using an augmented matrix)

My attempt so far is (let x= no. of 1 cent coins, y = etc...):
$$
x+y+z=12\\
x+5y+10z=86\\
x\geq0, y\geq0, z\geq0
$$
but I'm not sure how to formulate the last condition correctly in an augmented matrix.

Comment: @saulsplatz Sorry, question updated now

Comment: No apology necessary.  I'm trying to help you, not to criticize you.

Comment: The last condition can't really be formulated as part of the augmented matrix.  There's another condition: $x,y,z$ are integers.  You can't make that part of the augmented matrix either.  Put the first two equations in the matrix, and find the general form of the solution.  Then apply the remaining conditions.

Comment: @saulspatz I had guessed that might be the case alright, just wanted to confirm it with others. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Subtract the first from the second to get:
$$4y+9z=74 \Rightarrow z=\frac{74-4y}{9}=\frac{2(37-2y)}{9}.$$

Comment: Yes I see it now, and then impose my non-negativity constraints on each of the variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (somewhat) structured way to reach an answer:

Start with the greedy method to reach the sum $86$, regardless of number of coins. That's eight $10$'s, one $5$ and one $1$. Ten coins in total.

Now, repeatedly exchange one $10$ into two $5$'s until you have twelve coins. You end up with six $10$'s, five $5$'s and one $1$.

There are no other solutions. To see this, first see that if you have exactly one $1$, then the remaining eleven coins must be divided as above to make a sum of $85$. If you don't have one $1$, the next possibility is to have six of them (anywhere between one and six and you can't make the $6$ in $86$). And with six $1$'s, the largest sum you can possibly make is $66$. Finally, for the same reason, you can't have eleven $1$'s.